# Formula to substitute and add cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image: Excel screenshot]

What I'm trying to do is make the G4 cell the sum of the selected employees salary and the selected package. E4 and F4 (`Candidate` name and `Pkg` name) are both drop down lists with the relevant data in them.

I'm guessing I would need to somehow either substitute `Dan" and`Raise 2`for`63000`and`8000`or find the other instance of`Dan` and use the value of the cell to the right, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure if Google Docs has VLOOKUP, but that's what I would use in this case.

```
=VLOOKUP($E4,$B$4:$C$7,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($F4,$B$13:$C$15,2,FALSE)
```